# Cannot set landscape orientation in dynamic jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

```jasper
DynamicReport firstDynaRep = new DynamicReport();
firstDynaRep.setTemplateFileName("./landscape.jrxml");
firstDynaRep = firstReport.build();
```

DynamicReport not taking it as a template.
So the width of the page is not increased.
So is there any way to increase the width of the page in dynamicjasper report? (I want the report in landscape orientation.)

Answer (score 2):

Modify page size and orientation.

```
DynamicReportBuilder drb = new DynamicReportBuilder();
drb.setPageSizeAndOrientation(Page.Page_A4_Landscape());
```

OR

```
int w = ???
int h = ???
boolean portrait = false;
drb.setPageSizeAndOrientation(new Page(h, w, portrait);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used DynamicJasper for a long time, but I believe you should be using `setTemplateFileName()` on a `DynamicReportBuilder` and not on `DynamicReport`

```
DynamicReportBuilder drb = new DynamicReportBuilder();
drb.setTemplateFile("./landscape.jrxml");
DynamicReport firstDynaRep = drb.build();
```

Comment: I am used FastReportBuilder. I check the code just you specified ,but its not working with FastReportBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Page page = new Page(); 
page.setOrientationPortrait(false);

This will bring up the page in landscape mode